# How can I test whether or not my implementation of a WebAssembly interpreter conforms to the specfication?

Tags: webassembly

Imagine, I want to build a WebAssembly intepreter for a particular platform. I want to make sure that it is compliant with the standard.

**How can I test whether or not my WebAssembly interpreter works as specified by the standard?**

I found [this](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/tree/master/test/core) repository with what looks like automated tests. For example in [this file](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/master/test/core/fac.wast) they define the stuff they want to test at the top (all the function definitions), and at the end of the file there is a bunch of `assert_return` statements that seem to test whether or not those functions work correctly.

I could now use these tests to test my interpreter. If all of those tests pass, does it mean that my interpreter complies to the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [webassemblyjs](https://github.com/xtuc/webassemblyjs), a project which includes an interpreter implement.

If you look at the code, you can see that it includes the [WebAssembly specification](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/tree/master/test/core) as a submodule. The spec tests are run via the [helper package](https://github.com/xtuc/webassemblyjs/tree/master/packages/helper-testsuite-runner).

As you observed, the spec tests are written in WebAssembly Text Format, however they add additional test-specific instructions, e.g. `assert_return`. If you look at the `helper-testsuite-runner` project linked above, you can see that it implements these [spec tests specific commands](https://github.com/xtuc/webassemblyjs/blob/master/packages/helper-testsuite-runner/src/index.js#L64).